# Develop Java apps like android?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

this might seem like a really strange question but I would like to develop a Java application (for my computer) like I would when I develop for Android. It seems like it is a lot simpler making an android app than a regular application for my computer.

I really miss the drag-and-drop function for your XML-file and how you can launch different intents from you java-code. Is there a similar way to do that in eclipse but for a regular application? I don't like having to work with JFrame :/.

Comment: What would you like to send an intent for on an Desktop PC?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you'll find anything similar to intents for desktop apps, since it's a special feature of the android os. However something similar can easily be implemented, if you restrict yourself to intent delivery inside your own app. BTW: Netbeans has a forms designer (visual editor for JFrames, ect.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try JavaFX. It shares many commonalities with Android and a graphical drag'n'drop tool for building UIs (Scene Builder) that generates XML for you.

Comment: Yeah, it looks really promising!

Comment: @OXp1845 There is a special build of Eclipse called e(fx)clipse for JavaFX - http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some WYSISWYG editors for java applicaitons like [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html) for building the layout in xml. 
But i realy don't know what you would want to send intents for on a desktop PC

Answer (score 0):

No. Just learn JFrame, and you will learn a lot more Java. I honestly recommend you learn it, it's really helpful.

Comment: I really don't think JFrame is that good. Building a GUI in Java with swing or AWT is just a huge pain in the ass. Especially if you got a bigger project you will go crazy if you don't use at least JavaFX.

Comment: @Gumbo I generally don't like graphical programming tools, might just be me.

Comment: I generally hate creating graphical elements programmatically, i just love WYSIWYG editors. might just be me.